# auto layout constraint with UIControls to adjust varying font sizes

Tags: xcode5, height, uilabel, autolayout, uifont

I am working on Auto Layout in my app.I have applied the  fixed width and greater than equal constraint to my textual controls so that they may increase thin height if needed to accommodate the increased font size.

i need to know if its possible to apply 2 height constraints to a UIControl,I mean Height<=21 and height>=21 at the same time to enable my UIControl like labels to adjust height to include both increased and decreased font size than regular font size.
On what basis  and how my UILabel will decide whether to increase or decrease height ?

or it will randomly pick any of the 2 height constraints?

Any help will be appreciated
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your case, it'll always remain equal to 21.

If you decide to change the constraints to say >= 21 and < 21 it'll break and you'll see an exception being thrown, saying that's unable to satisfy both constraints.